# How does the browser render HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

If I have the following HTML div element:

```
<div id="outer-div" style="Certain-Style"> 

<div id="inner-div">
</div>
....
</div>
```

Then how the browser will implement/render these HTML elements? Does it start with outer div then inner div then go back to apply the CSS of `outer-div` then the CSS of `inner-div`?

Let us imagine that the style `Certain-Style` rotates the inner div by 90-degree clock-wise. The `inner-div` is an angularjs directive that displays other items according to the `inner-div` width. Does the rotation starts first then building the directive or it starts with building the directive then rotates?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick recap of the browser's steps:

1. Process HTML markup and build the DOM tree.
2. Process CSS markup and build the CSSOM tree.
3. Combine the DOM and CSSOM into a render tree.
4. Run layout on the render tree to compute geometry of each node.
5. Paint the individual nodes to the screen.

---

My source is the developers.google. Below is the link for more details.

[Render-tree Construction, Layout, and Paint](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I doubt google will delete its developers section anytime soon but I do appreciate the note, I did not think of that. Made the change to my answer.

Comment: You get a +1 from me for your changes, and addition of step summary to your answer.

Comment: To summarize:  it starts with outer div and apply its CSS style, then goes to the inner div and apply it CSS

Comment: I would say yes because when it creates the render tree it combines the visible nodes and traverses down.

Answer (score 0):

I think this video is best explanation about how rendering engine in browser work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CE12cBoalIc

Okey i will summarize for you from that video.

### Loader

First of all webkit (rendering engine used in chrome/safari) will be do action called Loader. This action in brief will be get your HTML file from server directly or cache storage.

After webkit get HTML file, then he will be do Tokenization to all your HTML syntax, and after Tokenization he will make DOM Tree for you.

And from Tokenization webkit also do action called Preload Scanner, this action in brief will look another action that must be to do later and webkit will shedule them. (Ex: @import, script tag using cdn, use external/internal image etc)

So at this phase, we get HTML, tokenize, parse, and we get a DOM tree.

### Layouting

After we get DOM tree from our HTML file the next action that webkit do is Layouting, this action basically will be create a layout from your html and dont be remember its just layouting not painting.

actually this is a long topic, because i dont fully understand whats is said in video so i just conclude this step will be create a layout from the previous DOM tree.

### Painting

Simply this action will draw to your layout from RenderObject that was created previously, and with this your UI will be displayed in your screen.